# Creating an IM bot

Tags: instant-messaging, bots

I am trying to create an IM bot and I haven't been able to find the necessary resources.

---

**UPDATE**

There was an issue with Imified making gtalk bots not appear online (and not responding), it works now so I'm closing this.

This [tutorial](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tutorial-create-bot-for-gtalk-yahoo-messenger/4354/) does work.

---

**Original question not deleted for reference purposes**

First, I did find a great tutorial on [How to Write Your Own IM Bot](http://www.labnol.org/internet/tutorial-create-bot-for-gtalk-yahoo-messenger/4354/), but it uses the IMified platform which looks dead (last blog post in septembre 2008, no feedback on their help forum, ...).

I did manage to create a beta bot using their service but as I can see in their help forum, it will never be online.

So, any one managed to do it?

**Notes**

I'm looking for something that would be:

- Free
- Works with PHP* or some free hosting solution (like IMified but that works)
- Works for Google Talk (I don't really care about the other)

Of course, do post answers about any solution that doesn't fit these criteria, it might help.

*I have a Linux hosting plan on GoDaddy

Comment: I have hosted a bot in imified (php) and even now my bot is active!!! No idea why its failing for you. When did you create the bot?

Comment: Today, but every message in the help forum seems to mention that their bot is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the tutorial in case it ever disappears:

> **Step 1**: Go to [imified.com](http://imified.com/) and request an invite. You should
>   also give your bot a decent name because you can have just one bot per
>   email address.
>
> **Step 2**: An email with a secret key should arrive in your Inbox the
>   next minute. Copy that key to the clipboard and go here to redeem that
>   key.
>
> **Step 3**: Now it's time to create a bot which is actually a simple
>   script that resides on your public web server. It could be in PHP,
>   Perl, Python or any other language. More here.
>
> This is the source of the PHP script I wrote for the labnol IM bot -
>   pretty self explanatory - it reads your message, gets the relevant
>   data from Google Suggest and echoes it back to the IM window.
>
> ```
> <?php   // Get all the related keywords from Google Suggest
>     $u = "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar";   $u = $u . "&q=" . $_REQUEST['msg'];
>
>     // Using the curl library since dreamhost doesn't allow fopen
>     $ch = curl_init();
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $u);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
>
>     $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
>     curl_close($ch);
>
>     // Parse the keywords and echo them out to the IM window
>     $result = $xml->xpath('//@data');
>     while (list($key, $value) = each($result))
>     {
>         echo $value ."<br>";
>     }
> ?>
> ```
>
> **Step 4**: Once your script is ready, put
>   it somewhere on your web server and copy the full URI to the
>   clipboard.
>
> Now login to your imified account, paste the script URL and add that
>   im bot your friends list. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

Google Talk uses jabber, where the protocol is called [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmpp). A quick google search for "xmpp bot php" led me [here](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/). This should be enough for a start ?